# Algorithm of minimal movement in 1D array to match positions of another array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve this algorithm exercise:

Given two arrays of positions (ints) with the same length, A and B, the subject is to find the minimal movement of elements at A to cover all positions of B.

Sample:
A: [1, 3]
B: [2, 4].

Answer: 2 (1->2, 3->4, (2-1)+(4-3)=2)

I tried to check every possible combination, but it's too slow.

I also tried to find for every element from A closest position of element at B, but it fails in some particular cases:

[1, 55, 100]
[2, 3, 99]

It would do: 1->2, 55->99, 100->3 (=142), which is further than 1->2, 55->3, 100->99 (=54).

Can somebody point me to the right solution without checking every combination?

Comment: How did we arrive at 54 in the last one? Shouldn't it be 52?

Comment: (55-3)=52, (100-99) = 1, (2-1)=1. 52+1+1=54

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm that comes to my mind is

1. Sort the 2 arrays
2. Check which one is bigger at a specific index
3. Add their subtraction in a variable

Here is the code I produced in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    int n;
    cin>>n; int a[n],b[n]; int ans=0; //Assuming you are given array size 
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>b[i];    
        
    sort(a,a+n); sort(b,b+n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(a[i]>b[i])
            ans+=(a[i]-b[i]);
        else
            ans +=(b[i]-a[i]);
    }
    cout<<ans;
}
```

Comment: How do you know that this always gives the correct answer?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Um you caught me there, I tried an induction proof for this but couldn't come up with a solution.